# Starting msfconsole with initial settings

Tags: msfconsole

I've asked this on security stackexchange, but they told me, it's a programming question, so they've closed: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270950/starting-msfconsole-with-initial-settings

I need to test several domains with an auxiliary scanner. All options are the same, except the `RHOSTS`.

Is it possible to write a little `sh` script that initializes the `msfconsole` on start?

For example:

```
use [auxiliary]
set SSL true
set RPORT 443
set PASS_FILE /path/myfile.txt
...
```